Handling duplicate Entity names in modular monolith architecture with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA
I am developing a Spring Boot application using a modular monolith architecture, aiming for high modularity where different modules (bounded contexts in DDD terminology) can operate independently but are part of the same application. Each module interacts with the same underlying database and utilizes Spring Data JPA for ORM. However, I'm encountering challenges with Hibernate entities that have the same name but represent different concepts across modules. For example, a Product entity in one module does not represent the same domain as a Product in another module.
Attempting to use entities with identical names across modules results in a org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException.
To isolate the entities and their transactions per module, I've explored creating separate EntityManagerFactory and TransactionManager instances for each module, configuring them as follows:
package com.example.bar;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BarContextConfig {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder
    ) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.example.bar")
                .persistenceUnit("barPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

I then import these configurations using the @Import annotation:
package com.example.app;

import com.example.bar.BarContextConfig;
import com.example.foo.FooContextConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({BarContextConfig.class, FooContextConfig.class})
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
}

The project structure is organized as follows:
|-java
|   |-com.example
|   |   |-app
|   |   |   |-SpringBootApp.java
|   |   |-bar
|   |   |   |-BarContextConfig.java
|   |   |   |-Product.java
|   |   |-foo
|   |   |   |-FooContextConfig.java
|   |   |   |-Product.java

While foo and bar being different, completely independent modules (bounded contexts).
While this approach works, it introduces significant boilerplate code for each module's configuration and violates the DRY principle.
Is there a streamlined method in Spring Boot for managing identical entity names in separate modules, reducing boilerplate code? Are there any established patterns or libraries/tools that simplify this process?
